# C++ String and char * c stype strings

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a c library which use char arrays as strings and i want to use c++   std::string on my code,
could someone help me how can i convert between char * c style strings and STL library strings ?

for example i have :

```
char *p="abcdef";
string p1;
```

and

```
string x="abc";
char *x1;
```

how can i convert p to p1 and x to x1

Comment: Note that `char* p="abcdef"` is at least very dangerous, if not outright wrong. That is because you cannot write to a string literal, so `p[0]='a'` throws you into Undefined Behavior Land. The pointer should be declared as `const` to make sure you don't accidentally do it. Also note that there is no such problem when constructing `std::strings` out of literals.

Answer (score 7):

Use string's assignment operator to populate it from a char *:

```
p1 = p;
```

Use string's c_str() method to return a const char *:

```
x1 = x.c_str();
```

Answer (score 5):

From char* to std::string :

```
char p[7] = "abcdef";
std::string s = p;
```

From std::string to char* :

```
std::string s("abcdef");
const char* p = s.c_str();
```

Comment: prettier, maybe, but less efficient. Your version creates a local copy of a string literal.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a `std::string` from a C string thus:

```
string p1 = p;
```

You can get a `const char *` from a `std::string` thus:

```
const char *x1 = x.c_str();
```

If you want a `char *`, you'll need to create a copy of the string:

```
char *x1 = new char[x.size()+1];
strcpy(x1, x.c_str());
...
delete [] x1;
```

Answer (score 2):

`string` has a constructor and an assignment operator that take a `char const*` as an argument, so:

```
string p1(p);
```

or

```
string p1;
p1 = p;
```

Should work. The other way around, you can get a `char const*` (not a char*) from a `string` using its `c_str()` method. That is

```
char const* x1 = x.c_str();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Removes character pointed to by "pch"
// from whatever string contains it.
void delchr(char* pch)
{
    if (pch)
    {
        for (; *pch; pch++)
            *pch = *(pch+1);
    }
}

void main()
{
    // Original string
    char* msg = "Hello world!";

    // Get pointer to the blank character in the message
    char* pch = strchr(msg, ' ');

    // Delete the blank from the message
    delchr(pch);

    // Print whatever's left: "Helloworld!"
    printf("%s\n", msg);
}
```